# Use of asynchronious BeginSend method

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

If you look at this [`Socket.BeginSend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9.aspx) method's signature:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginSend(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int size,
    SocketFlags socketFlags,
    AsyncCallback callback,
    Object state
)
```

I do not understand the difference between the `buffer` and `state` parameters. I have a custom class (that contains Socket field, and other custom properties).

What would be best way to send to on the other side, by creating a byte array and send them with 1st parameter (so in buffer) or would be better to send them with 6th parameter (state object)?

If I send them in the state, what is then the buffer used for? And if I send them in the buffer, is state only used for StateObject class?

One more thing, I have many custom (and different) classes which I want to send to the other side, and I will have to do some code that will "split" by some parameter. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET the `BeginXxx`/`EndXxx` async pattern usually looks something like:

```cs
IAsyncResult BeginXxx(..., AsyncCallback callback, Object state);
SomeResult EndXxx(IAsyncResult result);
```

The state object is any object you pass along so that you can retrieve state in your callback or the `EndXxx` method by calling the `IAsyncResult.AsyncState` property.

The state parameter is just used to support this pattern, it is not used to send anything through the socket. Only the data in the buffer will be sent through the socket.

I don't quite understand the last part of your question, but if you want to send objects through a socket, you could simply serialize your object to a `byte[]`, send it through the socket, and deserialize it on the other end. If that's not what you're asking, let me know.

Comment: Thx for your answer, this is what I have thought before too. I only had to make sure if state object is only for support parameter and no more - not for sending data. So I have to stick to the 1st paramter - to buffer (byte array) to send custom data. And I had in mind to use serialization (and deserialization on the other side) - as you stated.... Thx for the info.

Answer (score 1):

@Marcus' answer is right for the first part of your question; the state object does not get sent over the wire, it is only so you can associate a `EndXXX` call with an object from where the `BeginXXX` was called.

The second part:

> I have many custom (and different) classes which I want to send to the other side, and I will have to do some code that will "split" by some parameter. How to do that?

You need a protocol for this. The easiest way would be, in psuedo:

1. Serialize the object O you want to send into a byte array B with size S
2. Send S, which could be a `int` for example, as a byte array ([`BitConverter.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx)).
3. Receiver receives the first four bytes and reconstructs the `int`, so it now knows S.
4. Send all bytes of B
5. Receiver keeps reading until it has received S bytes, so it can reconstruct B and deserialize the object O.

Comment: Thx, this is in a big help, what I would like to know more, is how to "split" data, so it will be sent in pieces (you said, 1st an S, then whole O, and even O in pieces. Is there any particular way to do the "split", or this is defined by the constant length of the byte array?  thx in advance.

Comment: @MitjaBonca there is no splitting using sockets. If you send three objects, it might be received in one receive call, and vice versa. So you'll have to determine (that's the protocol) that you first send N bytes indicating the length of the following message (N=4 for Int32).

Comment: I would really appreacite for a simple example of points fro 1-5. I would be more then happy. I then owe you one :)

Comment: "it might be received in one call..." - does it mean the code does by it self, what to send?? Or this is defined by the size of the buttfer?

Comment: @MitjaBonca many factors decide in how many receive calls a sent buffer is received, for example the network stack used by the OS'es on both sides, routers in between, various buffer sizes, network congestion and Nagle. You don't have any influence on most of this, so just implement a simple protocol. If you do exactly as I typed out in psuedo, you will be able to exchange objects. I think I gave enough hints in the text for you to do it, I can't write a wroking solution for you, sorry.

Comment: Thx, I understand many more things. Btw, if you wound written a solution for me, all the charm dissapears, right? :) I will try to do some tests, and let you know. ok? Stay tuned, maybe I would have any additional question. Just one more thing here: so what`s the point in defining a fixed size of a buffer (byte array)?

Comment: And what is the difference between using byte array, and a List of bytes (this is the 1st overload in BeginXXX/SendXXX methods.